# Autogrow table cell and contenteditable div inside it

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make autogrow table cell related to size of it child - contenteditable div?

**css:**

```
table {
    border:1px solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    width:350px;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid;
    position:relative;
    padding:0px;
    height:100px;
}
div {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;  
    position:relative;  
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

**html:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><div contenteditable>one</div></td>
        <td><div contenteditable>two</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div contenteditable>three</div></td>
        <td><div contenteditable>four</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In my example table cell does not change it own size and div content overlaps.

http://jsfiddle.net/wxduS/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modified CSS:

```css
table {
    border:1px solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    width:350px;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

td {
    position:relative;
    padding:0px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    vertical-align: top;
}

div {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100px;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;    
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

and [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wxduS/12/).

Comment: your example is good but div height is not 100%. If i set it to 100% div overlaps the parent table.

Comment: Ok, changed the div so that now it can have the height 100%.

Comment: many thanks to you. You saved me twice this week.
could you please check http://jsfiddle.net/wxduS/14/? if i change min-height and height using js div overlaps the parent table again :(

Comment: Thanks :-) If you set the fixed height, the text will exceed the div. You can set additionaly this style: `div {overflow-y: auto;}` so the browser automatically add vertical scrollbar when needed.

Comment: yes i know, but scrollbar is highly undesirable. i want to be able autogrow td and div simultaneously according to div content.

Comment: By setting only min-height with jQuery it works, but it is quite a clumsy solution. http://jsfiddle.net/lalatino/wxduS/16/    I would advice you to ask people a new question, that you have this code - maybe somebody will advice you some better solution on how to equalize div heights without javascript. That CSS `div {height:100%;}` has no effect. I am clueless here, why it doesn't work.

Comment: also this javascript has similar effect: `$('table div').keyup(function(){$('table div').each(function(){$(this).css('min-height',$(this).parent().height());});});`

Comment: i've asked new question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003641/div-with-dynamic-content-inside-table-cell-and-table-row-height-alignment