# Div with dynamic content inside table cell and table row height alignment

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to place div inside table cells. Div and cell height should be always aligned according to the dynamic content of the div.

Div height increases if text is inserted inside it but other div's heights remain the same:
[image: Inserted text]

**example:** http://jsfiddle.net/BWYQg/

As workaround i use js to expand remaining div's heights (increasing div min-height), but
if content is cleared after insertion i see the following picture:
[image: Removed text]

**example:** http://jsfiddle.net/BWYQg/1/

So the question is how to make td and div heights always aligned according to the content of the divs?

**UPD:**
Content of the div should be editable (`<div contenteditable>`), so div height increases after text typing.

Comment: Why do you use div inside tables? Try using div based columns. This may be useful: http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the equal height function. http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/8-awesome-jquery-tips-and-tricks Hope this help.

```
function equalHeight(group) {
    tallest = 0;
    group.each(function() {
        thisHeight = $(this).height();
        if(thisHeight > tallest) {
            tallest = thisHeight;
        }
    });
    group.height(tallest);
}



$(document).ready(function() {
    equalHeight($(".recent-article"));
    equalHeight($(".footer-col"));
});
```

Comment: this one does not decrease height after content clearance. Also does not work if i type something inside div.

Comment: you removed divs from table cell, i know it works. but i'm looking for solution where divs are inside cell

Comment: @amit +1 for your effort and solution. And I think this mod will work. http://jsfiddle.net/BWYQg/48/

Comment: @Stano you did it again :) it works great in Chrome but works strange in FF. Div borders replicates (not expands) each time when i type.

Comment: Firefox converts new line character in editablearea to `<br/>` tag, Chrome creates new empty `<div>`. That's why the algorythm worked wrong. It needs more specific css and jquery selectors. Here is updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BWYQg/54/

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably recommend using a jQuery equal heights type of plug in such as this one:

You simply need to add the same class onto each DIV and reference that when calling the plug in.

http://www.cssnewbie.com/download/jquery.equalheights.js

So you need to download the equal heights JS file from the page above and include it on your web page AFTER you have called jQuery.

Then you call the script like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.myDiv').equalHeights();

});
```

Comment: as i understand all of div should be in the same container. it's not suitable in my case.

Comment: @user947668 - The DIVs don't have to be in the same container. They just have to have the same class name.

Comment: @user947668 - I've linked to a different plug in that does the job and doesn't rely on a container DIV as you had correctly pointed out that the other one did. THis new one simply requires all the DIVs to have the same class name.

Comment: @user947668 - I've updated your fiddle by placing a background colour on the DIVs and putting some more text in the middle DIV. I think you'll see that this shows that it works unless I'm seeing things!http://jsfiddle.net/BWYQg/36/

Comment: if you try to type something inside one of cell you'll see that div scrollbars appear and div doesn't change its own height.

Comment: If you want it to do that you'll need to call the equal heights function after text is entered, or when the div is dynamically updated or something. I think I've done what I can helping you get the DIVs to be an equal height. Hope the time I've spent trying to help has been of some use at least.

Answer (score 0):

You can always get the .height() from the element that has the content and set it to the other elements on the fly. for example:

```
var $tdContentHeight = $('tr td .has-content').height();
$('tr').find('td .has-no-content').each(function() { $(this).height($tdContentHeight)})
```

further you could compare heights and always choose the tallest height and asign them to all other elements in the tr.

**FIDDLE UPDATE AGAIN. CHECK HERE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/BWYQg/31/

Comment: thanks for example. but the task is a little bit more complicated. Divs are editable and should be resized according to the typed content. I've tried to specify height of divs after each keyup event http://jsfiddle.net/BWYQg/17/ , but nothing happens.

Comment: this one works only for one cell. if i try to edit more than one of cells div overlaps parent table.